# What is #ADDIN? error caused by Apache POI?

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I'm creating a spreadsheet with a block of SUMIFS formula cells. It creates fine, POI doesn't complain on cell.setCellFormula() and doesn't complain on evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell() either.

The SUMIFS cells are like this:

```
SUMIFS(raw!$C$2:$C$2625, raw!$D$2:$D$2625, C$1, raw!$B$2:$B$2625, $A2)
```

Where "raw" is the name of a second sheet where the raw data comes from.

When I open the spreadsheet in LibreOffice Calc, the cells have the correct formulas in them, but all show #ADDIN? instead of the value. F9 does nothing. Ctrl+Shift+F9 does nothing.

However, if I touch the formula (ie add a space and delete it) then press enter, the cell magically has the correct value in it. So LibreOffice clearly accepts the formula as-is.

How do I get around this error? Or do I have to use some other XLS-writing library?

Comment: What version of Apache POI is this with? And if it isn't the latest (3.11), what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: @Gagravarr It was 3.11. As I note in my answer, switching to the XML output format solved the problem, and the workbook opened fine in LibreOffice.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer -- SUMIFS() is apparently not supported by HSSFWorkbook, but it *is* supported by XSSFWorkbook. Changed one line in my code to create an XSSF workbook instead, and the emitted XLSX file works just fine with LibreOffice.

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference in formula support between the two formats - they use exactly the same evaluation logic. Are you sure you were evaluating the formula cell correctly before you saved?

Comment: I changed one line of code -- from wbook=new HSSFWorkbook() to wbook=new XSSFWorkbook -- the cell creation and evaluation code does not change.

Comment: Probably worth raising that as a bug then, along with a short junit unit test shorting it - there shouldn't be any difference between the two formats on that sort of thing!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `_xlfn.SUMIFS` instead of `SUMIFS`. It worked fine for me! Or maybe you are running into an error due to lack of parenthesis around the formula, check this out: [Apache POI 3.x - Logical formula resulting in #VALUE! (error) only in MS Excel 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31551216/apache-poi-3-x-logical-formula-resulting-in-value-error-only-in-ms-excel-2/31551217#31551217)