# Apache POI 3.x - Logical formula resulting in #VALUE! (error) only in MS Excel 2010

Tags: excel, apache-poi, excel-2010, excel-2013

I've developed a code that creates a XLS file using Apache POI 3.9.
The sheet has two columns that contains only boolean values, as shown below:

[image: xls file opened in Excel 2010 in Portuguese]

The generated XLS file was opened using a MS Excel 2010 in Portuguese (pt-BR), thus consider VERDADEIRO as TRUE and FALSO as FALSE. The 3rd column contains the formula `INT(AND(L2,NOT(M2)))`
varying references L2 and M2 for each row. This formula is a logical expression that has its result converted to integer. However, when the file is opened using MS Excel 2010 the formula results in error (represented by #VALUE!). I've tested the same file using OpenOffice Calc, LibreOffice Calc and MS Excel 2011 for Mac and it worked fine for both of them.
The error disappeared and the correct value was displayed when I pressed F2 and then hit Enter for each cell.

Comment: Why are you using an old version of Apache POI? What happens if you upgrade to the latest one, 3.13 beta 1 as of writing?

Comment: I've just tested using the lastest stable version: 3.12, same problem... This time, I used MS Excel 2013 for Windows and didn't work. The funny thing is that there's no problem using MS Excel 2011 for Mac nor using OpenOffice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the formula adding parenthesis around the function call `NOT(M2)` 

`INT(AND(L2,NOT(M2)))` ====>  `INT(AND(L2,(NOT(M2))))` and the problem was solved.